# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/uncrypt_file: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-source, ota

It confused me with this **Error**:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/uncrypt_file: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

when I used this method`RecoverySystem.installPackage()`,and my ota path was in **sdcard**.My android version is 6.0.1,and the source code of`RecoverySystem.installPackage()`as follows:

```
public static void installPackage(Context context, File packageFile)
    throws IOException {
    String filename = packageFile.getCanonicalPath();

    FileWrite uncryptFile=new FileWriter(UNCRYPT_FILE);
    try{
        uncryptFile.write(filename+"\n");
    }finally{
        uncryptFile.close();
    }

    Log.w(TAG, "!!! REBOOTING TO INSTALL " + filename + " !!!");

    if(filename.startWith("/data/")){
       filename="@/cache/recovery/block.map";
    }  
    final String filenameArg = "--update_package=" + filename;
    final String localeArg = "--locale=" + Locale.getDefault().toString();
    bootCommand(context, filenameArg, localeArg);
}
```

Comment: What is your apps installation folder?

Comment: Well that path does not exist to begin with. So what do you expect?

Comment: `,and my ota path was in sdcard`. Then tell which path exactly.

Comment: I compiled this  otaUpdateAPK in AOSP,and put it in /system/app  @Murf

Comment: My update.zip path is  `/sdcard/update.zip`,which `"/sdcard/update.zip".getCanonicaLpath()` shows the exact path is `/storage/media/0/update.zip` @greenapps

Comment: You should put in the the folder `/system/priv-app`

Comment: it works, thank you @Murf

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working since your default app is installed in the folder `/system/app` folder. You should move it to `/system/priv-app`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, when I move the app in the folder /system/priv-app.
The app I'm writing is just a activity to starting my service /onCreate.  I have set in my manifest.xml==>
 
android.permission.INTERNET"/ WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /REBOOT/ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM/DELETE_CACHE_FILES.

```
W/System.err( 1744): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCES (Permission denie
W/System.err( 1744):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:429)
W/System.err( 1744):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
W/System.err( 1744):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
W/System.err( 1744):    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.os.RecoverySystem.bootCommand(RecoverySystem.java:408)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:337)
W/System.err( 1744):    at com.lcupdate.UsbUpdateService.rebootToInstall(UsbUpdateService.java:46)
W/System.err( 1744):    at com.lcupdate.UsbUpdateService.checkZipExist(UsbUpdateService.java:58)
W/System.err( 1744):    at com.lcupdate.UsbUpdateService.onCreate(UsbUpdateService.java:74)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2578)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 1744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
W/System.err( 1744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
W/System.err( 1744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
W/System.err( 1744):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```